# JavaScript curly braces not working embeded in string for jsx file in vs code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio

I am working a simple `react` app where I need to insert some `JavaScript` into a `url` in an `img` tag

[image]

props.monster.id should return an int to be used in the url. However it is not working.
Also the js isn't displaying as it should in vs code. This is how it looks in the tutorial I am following.

[image]

The code is typed in identically so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.This is in a `jsx` file.

Comment: use backticks: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 4):

use backticks (``) for doing that not ''

just use this:

```
src={`https://robohash.org/${props.monster.id}?set=set2`}
```

you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)